# Connecting dokku MySQL to a database GUI (e.g. Sequel Ace or Sequel pro)

Tags: mysql, dokku, sequelpro

I have a dokku installation with MySQL. I'm trying to figure out how I can connect my MySQL database in dokku to a database GUI like Sequel ace or Sequel pro.

I already made a database and linked it to my (Laravel) app, which works fine! But I can't figure out which username / password / host I need to fill in, in sequel ace to connect to the database inside dokku.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Host name, user name and password does not depend on the client software you use. It depends on your mysql configuration. Whatever details you use for Laravel must work for your gui tools as long as they are on the same computer as your Laravel app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

On my Dokku server i connect my laravel app with a database url to the mysql server. The url looks something like this: mysql://mysql:{
some_random_code }@dokku-mysql-staging-db:3306/{db_name}

My question is, can i remotly connect to the mysql database in dokku with, for example, sequal ace.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

1. expose your mysql db to a port `dokku mysql:expose <db_name> <port>`
2. run `dokku mysql:info <db_name>` en look for the "Dsn" (DATABASE_URL). It looks something like mysql://mysql:<random_code>@dokku-mysql-staging-db:3306/<db_name>
3. This URL has al the info you need
   `[database type]://{username}:{password}@{inner docker host name}/{db_name}`
4. Now you kan connect remotly with your DB GUI

I connected succesfully using Sequel Pro with the following info:

```
Host: { your servers IP address }

Username: { username from DB URL }

Password: { password from DB URL }

Port: { port you exposed the DB on }
```

PS: i read somewhere that you need to have UFW disable on your server, but i'm not in server managment, so i don't know the consequence of this.